# Using a property of initially undefined variable for useEffect dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

> TL;DR: Want to use listRef.current.clientWidth for useEffect dependency.

I wanted to make a list where it automatically resizes its item's widths according to list's width. I'm so close but I can't detect the change of `listRef.current.clientWidth` which is `<div className="dynamic-list">`'s width. At the first run listRef is null, so I can't have `listRef.current.clientWidth` for the useEffect dependency. `listRef ? listRef.current.clientWidth : null` for the dependency also doesn't work with `use simple dependency warning`.

```
const DynamicList = ({
  dataSource, renderItem, itemMaxWidth, itemHeight,
  margin, height = 500, width = 700 }) => {
  const windowWidth = useWindowDimensions().width; 
  const [itemStyle, setItemStyle] = useState({ width: itemMaxWidth, height: itemHeight });
  const [currentWidth, setCurrentWidth] = useState(null);
  const listRef = useRef();


  useEffect(() => {
    if (listRef) {
      const num = Math.floor(listRef.current.clientWidth / itemMaxWidth)
      console.log(
        num,
        listRef.current.clientWidth,
        listRef.current
      )
      setItemStyle((pre) => ({
        ...pre,
        height: itemHeight,
        margin: margin,
        width: (listRef.current.clientWidth / num) - (margin ? margin * 2 : 0),
      }))
    }

  }, [listRef, windowWidth, itemMaxWidth, margin, itemHeight, width])

  return (
    <div
      className="dynamic-list"
      ref={listRef}
      style={{
        width: width,
        height: height
      }}
    >
      {
        dataSource.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div style={itemStyle} key={index}>
              {renderItem(item, index)}
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default DynamicList;
```

- Any tips on making this better would be really appreciated.

Comment: you can use callback ref

Comment: Not sure if I get what you're trying to do. 1, If you want to detect changes why are you using `useRef`? `useRef` doesn't notify you when its content changes. 2, I don't get how `listRef` is `null`. You create a reference there. `listRef.current` might be `null` since you don't provide an initial value. If that's a problem you could provide one.

Comment: @thisismydesign 1. In order to get the width of the `div`, I had to access it via `ref`of the  `div` 2. After googling, I guess you're right. `useRef` returns an object. I don't know why I said `listRef` is `null`. I probably should've written `listRef.current` was `null`. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: So then what about assigning a starting state? E.g. `useRef({})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using callback ref like @TopW3 said, I was able to solve the problem. Not fully satisfied though. 
[Article that also helped me solve the problem](https://dev.to/thekashey/the-same-useref-but-it-will-callback-8bo)

```
const DynamicList = ({
  dataSource, renderItem, itemMaxWidth, itemHeight,
  margin, height = 500, width = 700 }) => {
  const windowWidth = useWindowDimensions().width; // 윈도우 크기 변화 감지용
  const [itemStyle, setItemStyle] = useState({
    width: itemMaxWidth,
    height: itemHeight,
    margin: margin
  });
  const [listWidth, setListWidth] = useState(null);

  const onListRefSet = useCallback((ref) => {
    if (ref)
      if (ref.current)
        setListWidth(ref.current.clientWidth);
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (listWidth) {
      const num = Math.floor(listWidth / itemMaxWidth);
      setItemStyle((pre) => ({
        ...pre,
        width: (listWidth / num) - (margin ? margin * 2 : 0),
      }))
    }
  }, [listWidth, itemMaxWidth, margin, itemHeight, windowWidth])

  return (
    <div
      className="dynamic-list"
      ref={onListRefSet}
      style={{
        width: width,
        height: height,
        minWidth: itemMaxWidth
      }}
    >
      {
        dataSource.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div style={itemStyle} key={index}>
              {renderItem(item, index)}
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default DynamicList;
```